# How can i fetch my get variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've made a controller named `LibraryController`, it has a `ActionResult` named `Movie` which takes on parameter (int id).

I've tried to add the following route in `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Movie",
            url: "Library/Movie/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Movie", id = (string)null }
        );
```

But in the method `Movie(string id)` id is null, even if i redirect the browser to `/Library/Movie/1`

Whats up with that? The `MapRoute` is defined before `Default`.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because `(int)null` does not compile... Do you have `(int?)null` and `int?` in your action? Do you have some other custom routes? By the way with this given information I'm not able to repro your issue: in a new MVC4 project with this route when I navigate to `/Library/Movie/1` I get the correct paramter value 1 in the `id`

Comment: Sorry, typo... its string! edited!

Comment: Jason can you post your Controller code? I think overall you would want to use id = UrlParameter.Optional or id = "MovieId". What kind of URL are you after? Just the /Library/Movie/1?

Comment: I believe nemesv is correct since the default routing and having (int? id) within your controllers Index/Details method will show the right results. Of course you'll want to grab your Movie object by the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, try using

```
id = UrlParameter.Optional or id ="MovieId" or id = ""


routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Movie",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Library", action = "Movie", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Then your controller would look like:

```
    public class LibraryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Movie(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Movie m = _context.Movies.Find(id);

            if (m == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(m);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UrlParameter.Optional`

Otherwise most likely the internals parsing the route will invoke your action/method with `null`.

The correct implementation of an optional parameter value for a route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Movie",
    url: "Library/Movie/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Library",
                    action = "Movie",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Your controller and action should be:

```
public class LibraryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Movie(string id)
    {
        // do something with id here
        return View();
    }
}
```